# How can i get data from custom post type using WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest

**I want to GET data from my custom post type using  WP REST API.**

My Custom post type is **"result"** and I have tried with this parameters.

```
http://ejobbox.com/wp-json/wp/v2/result/?

http://ejobbox.com/wp-json/wp/v2/result/?per_page=10
```

**and also with**

```
http://ejobbox.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?post_type=result
```

But I am not able to get data using custom Post type.

**I have also added this into my custom post type**

```
'show_in_rest'=> true,
'rest_base'          => 'result',
'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
```

Still I didn't get any result.

Please, can you tell me what I am doing wrong here and what can I do to get data from my custom post type?
Please Give me a suggestion for this.

**My Function.php (Custom post type) code is Here:**

```
function codexres_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Result'
    );
    register_post_type( 'result', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codexres_custom_init' );


function codex_result_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Result', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Result', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Result', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Result', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

        'view_item'          => __( 'View Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

        'all_items'          => __( 'All Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Result:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Result found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Result found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'show_in_rest'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-admin-users',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => __('result', 'result')),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'rest_base'          => 'result',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'taxonomies'       => array('result','category', 'post_tag')

    );

    register_post_type( 'result', $args );
}
```

Comment: Seems like it is working right now. I am getting data if i visit this url http://ejobbox.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?post_type=result

Comment: It is wrong data that get form my default post type:

please check this (default post) and compare it with custom post so you understand this. it will same data.

http://ejobbox.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10

Comment: Hello Friends can you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you did wrong:**

You have two function `codexres_custom_init` and `codex_result_init` And both function registering same post type which is not required. Although for second function `codex_result_init` you did not add it to `add_action('init','function_name')`. So in your case the function `codexres_custom_init` is not required. For further understaning on custom post type creation can see this [document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

[Rest api for custom post type](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/)

Try this , what i can see is that, you register result post type twice. although you did not init the main one.

```
function codex_result_init() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Result', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Result', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Result', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Result', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

    'view_item'          => __( 'View Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

    'all_items'          => __( 'All Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Result', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Result:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Result found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Result found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'show_in_rest'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-admin-users',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => __('result', 'result')),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'rest_base'          => 'result',
    'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies'       => array('result','category', 'post_tag')

);

register_post_type( 'result', $args );
}
  add_action( 'init', 'codex_result_init' );
```

Just eliminate below code:

```
function codexres_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Result'
    );
    register_post_type( 'result', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codexres_custom_init' );
```

Dont inculde this ya.

Answer (score 10):

This is how I get data back from my custom post type in WordPress using REST API.

`http://ejobbox.com/wp-json/wp/v2/customposttype` This will return the first 10 results of the custom post type entries.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is using Custom Post type UI *plugin* - you'll need to go into the post type setting and do this through the UI.

[image]

Comment: what's the url for this new custom post type?

Comment: I'm not sure why the docs are THE MOST CONFUSING THING EVER (for me...) https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/  I'll double-check... but here's a starting point.

Comment: https://perpetual.education/wp-json/acf/v3/person  (for example) - this is one of our (unfinished) custom post types. (and you probably need to add acf to json plugin.

Comment: thanks, now I'm using another plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-routes-custom-endpoints-for-wp-rest-api/

Comment: That seems like a great option!

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
//add this to your functions.php file in your theme folder
function sb_add_cpts_to_api( $args, $post_type ) {
if ( 'result' === $post_type ) {
$args['show_in_rest'] = true;
}
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'sb_add_cpts_to_api', 10, 2 );
```

i got that from [here](https://scottbolinger.com/custom-post-types-wp-api-v2/)

it worked like voodo